# How to Add CNAME in Azure DNS via C# code

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, virtual-machine

I have requirement to have multiple subdomain.
My site is hosted in virtual machine with name test.mydomain.com
I have manually added CNAME Testing1 in azureDNS and configure that in IIS site bindings Testing1.mydomain.com. and this is working

But i want to make it automatic.intead of manual process. need to do it from code or from powershell.

Anyone having knowledge about this please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start by creating a Service Principal account since it's the authority you'll use to authenticate via the SDK into Azure.

Here's the documentation to create a service principal:

- [Authenticating with a password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-6.3.0)
- [Authenticating with a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-authenticate-service-principal-powershell)

Install the following packages to your C# project:
[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns/)
[Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication/)
[Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager/3.14.0-preview) (note this is a preview package)

You'll need to populate the following variables for the sample below:

`tenantID: The ID of the tenant your Service Principal and DNS resource are on`

`clientId: The Service Principal identifier`

`secret: Whatever your secret mechanism is for the Service Principal you picked above`

`subscriptionId: The ID of the Azure subscription your DNS resource is on`

`resourceGroupName: The name of the resource group your DNS resource is located in`

`zoneName: The name of the DNS zone you're modifying (the host name)`

`recordSetName: A name to assign to the record set`

Then you'll use the following logic to create the necessary CNAMEs necessary in Azure DNS using the Service Principal values.

```
var dnsClient = new DnsManagementClient(serviceCreds);
dnsClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

// Create record set parameters
var recordSetParams = new RecordSet();
recordSetParams.TTL = 3600;
recordSetParams.CnameRecord = new CnameRecord
{
  Cname = "<Your CNAME Value>"
};

//Create the record in Azure DNS
await dnsClient.RecordSets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, zoneName, recordSetName, RecordType.Cname, recordSetParams);
```

Comment: I am planning to use powershell like in which i dont have to get tenant id and client id. and i tested one script i was able to add through powershell . so now i am planning to execute that query from C# code . What do you think about it ?

Comment: PS C:\> $Records = @()
PS C:\> $Records += New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -Cname test.mydomain.com
PS C:\> $RecordSet = New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "mycname" -RecordType CNAME -ResourceGroupName "sonic" -TTL 3600 -ZoneName "myzone.com" -DnsRecords $Records               This script work for me

Comment: Presumably you logged into your Powershell session though (likely interactively). If you're aiming for an autonomous solution, you'll need a service principal.

Comment: Connect-AzureRmAccount this was my first command from powershell to connect my account first,

Comment: If you pop open your AAD tenant and create a new app registration, it's the identity equivalent of a service principal (you'll see the tenant ID and client ID up in the property overview) and have the option to use the GUI to define the authentication method if you're not comfortable setting it up via PS

Comment: Details on my latest comment at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal

Comment: My site is hosted in Virtual machine not in azure service and i dont want to use azure active directory so i think without that i can't get tenantid and client id . is that possible ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235871/discussion-between-whit-waldo-and-jahimaf).